# Add two textviews end to end in android xml

Tags: android, textview

I want to add a textview right at the end of another textview, ie not in next line, but where previous textview ends, in xml file. Just like:

```
| <TextView1><TextView2>    |


| aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbb    |
```

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" 
        android:ellipsize="none"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="bbb" />

</LinearLayout>
```

but text "bbb" is not shown. Can anyone help?

Comment: if your text CAN be that long, then why are you trying to fit in both textboxes side-by-side?

Comment: Do you really want to keep ellipsize as none? since if its your requirement then its not possible to keep both textViews on same line, if not then please see my answer.

Comment: @ GAMA..not side by side but end to end.

Answer (score 0):

use weight sum .....

I have provided both 50% space you can change as per your requirement.......

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" 
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:layout_weight=".5"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="bbb"
            android:layout_weight=".5" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

as per requirement ......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" 
        android:ellipsize="none"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="bbb"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/textView"
         />

</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: In this case b's are coming in first line only.

Comment: no.. I just want that new text in different textView doesn't start from next line(like if the orientation is vertical).It should start from same line where first textView's text ends.

Comment: either you need to scroll the view to see "bbb" or you have to ellipsis the "aaaaaaaaaa.." or you have to some of the text of "aaaaaaaa...." to next line .. what 'll you prefer?

Answer (score 0):

Use following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="bbb" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have provided `android:ellipsize="none"` as none and giving a very long text to textView.

just provide `android:ellipsize="end"` and you will be able to see second textView.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" 
    android:ellipsize="none"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="bbb" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: He wants to have textView side by side. The above code will place seconde textView below first one.

Comment: bbb goes to next line..It should be right after, where a's end

Answer (score 0):

Use a RelativeLayout and have your "aaaa..." text view align to the left of the "bbb" textview. You can either remove `maxLines` or set it to some other value if you want multiple lines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/date"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="bbb" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="fill">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView" 
        android:text="bbb"             
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/date" 
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"             
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView"
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:ellipsize="none"  />   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What if i do not want it in a single line? What if i want to put at the end of a string that has two or three lines depending of the phone resolution?

Answer (score 0):

it's simple use one textView and inside your cod use `append` method and add some space before your second text :)