# How can I prevent a user from deleting pre-existing text in an EditText widget?

Tags: android, kotlin, text, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` with some pre-existing text that MUST NOT be deleted. The user should only be allowed to append text in the view.

The solution I have right now can be seen below, where I check if the new length of the `EditText` is shorter than the original text. If it is, the user has attempted to delete a character so I just repopulate the view with the original text and move the cursor. The problem with this solution is that the user could just enter text that is longer than the original length, then change the position of the cursor to somewhere within the original text, and finally delete characters.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val originalText = "Hello"
    binding.et.setText(originalText)
    
    binding.et.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            s?.let {
                if (s.length < originalText.length) {
                    binding.et.setText(originalText)
                    binding.et.setSelection(originalText.count())
                }
            }
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
    })
}
```

What should I do? I'm open to all ideas.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I've also tried combining an `EditText` and a `TextView` (as some have suggested) but the layout is difficult to achieve because both the original text and the new text can span multiple lines. My solution above contains one word in the original text but it could be many. So I need to cater for this scenario:

[image: textview and edittext]

...where the white box represents the `TextView` and the red box represents the `EditText`.

I don't think Bö macht Blau's answer will work either because the prefix is in its own "column".

I think I will have to use Zain's solution with (`startsWith()`) or create a custom view (though I've never done one of these before).

Comment: Consider using [InputFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter)

Comment: An EditText isn't the right tool for that.  I'd look at either a combo of a TextField and an EditText, or writing a custom view with that functionality that could derive from EditText

Comment: This is hacky but why don't you add a TextView with your fixed text to the left of the EditText and style both views in a way so that they look like one single view.

Comment: I've updated my post to include more detail about what I've tried and what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please consider @Gabe Sechan advice in OP comments that the `EditText` alone is not the optimum solution for that.

In case you still need to use `EditText` then you can change the condition to check that the returned `CharSequence` of the `EditText` watcher starts with the original text using [`startsWith()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/starts-with.html) method

```
et.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        s?.let {

            if (!s.startsWith(originalText)) {

                if (s.length <= originalText.length) {
                    et.setText(originalText)
                    et.setSelection(originalText.count())
                } else {
                    et.setText(originalText + s.subSequence(originalText.length, s.length))
                    et.setSelection(s.count())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
})
```

Comment: I've updated my post and I think your solution with startsWith() might be my only option.

Comment: I saw that you need `EditText` to be contiguous to the end of the `TextView`..  this would be some how complex.. and can change from a screen size/resolution to another (you need to calculate exactly when the text ends relative to the screen) ..  also for text size will be a parameter to this calculation .. you can try with a `Custom` view

Comment: @BobSacamano please have look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896157/add-two-textviews-end-to-end-in-android-xml)

Comment: I've decided to go with your EditText solution for now. The other answers were interesting but ultimately they weren't perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a text field, that's a combination of a `TextInputEditText` and a `TextInputLayout`. Then you can set a prefix like so:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         app:prefixText="@string/prefix_text">

     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The prefix will be visible as soon as the `TextInputEditText` gains focus. Since it is not part of the `EditText` content, it can't be modified by the users.

Useful links:

- [documentation for `TextInputLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout)
- [overview of style options](https://material.io/components/text-fields/android)

Comment: Elegant solution +1 for using a single view

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work. See my update

Comment: @BobSacamano - yes, this will only work well if one can be sure that the prefix is rather short.

Answer (score 0):

This check should work:

```kotlin
if (s.substring(0, 4) == originalText) {
  // update text
}
```

But consider looking into [InputFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter), as a comment suggested.